# want to convert a image generator C# code to JAVA

Tags: java, image-processing, coordinates, screen, screenshot

So I got one Class and its methods written in C#
basically what it does is it takes a screenshot of a part of the screen by x and y coordinates and height, width
I want to convert this c# code to JAVA so that I can use it in my Desktop UI automation project
so this is a utility which takes image based on "X" and "Y" coordinates of the screen
please note: I already tried online converters and the code which it generates shows library package errors

Below is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace myClass
{
    class ImageCapture
    {

        public static void Capture(string fileName, Point firstCoordinate, Point secondCoordinate, int enlargeImageByPercentage=0)
        {
            var tmpImg = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData).Replace("Roaming", "Local") + "\\temp", Path.GetFileName(fileName));

            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(firstCoordinate.X, firstCoordinate.Y, secondCoordinate.X - firstCoordinate.X, secondCoordinate.Y - firstCoordinate.Y);
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
            g.CopyFromScreen(rect.Left, rect.Top, 0, 0, bmp.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
            bmp.Save(tmpImg, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            g.Dispose();
            bmp.Dispose();
            


            if (File.Exists(fileName)) File.Delete(fileName);
            if (enlargeImageByPercentage != 0)
            {
                Image imgToEnlarge = Image.FromFile(tmpImg);
                Image resizedImg = resizeImage(tmpImg, new Size(imgToEnlarge.Size.Width * enlargeImageByPercentage, imgToEnlarge.Size.Height * enlargeImageByPercentage));
                resizedImg.Save(fileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            }
            else
            {
                File.Copy(tmpImg, fileName, true);
            } 
        }



        private static Image resizeImage(string imgToResize, Size size)
        {
            Image _img = Image.FromFile(imgToResize);
            //Get the image current width  
            int sourceWidth = _img.Width;
            //Get the image current height  
            int sourceHeight = _img.Height;
            float nPercent = 0;
            float nPercentW = 0;
            float nPercentH = 0;
            //Calulate  width with new desired size  
            nPercentW = ((float)size.Width / (float)sourceWidth);
            //Calculate height with new desired size  
            nPercentH = ((float)size.Height / (float)sourceHeight);
            if (nPercentH < nPercentW)
                nPercent = nPercentH;
            else
                nPercent = nPercentW;
            //New Width  
            int destWidth = (int)(sourceWidth * nPercent);
            //New Height  
            int destHeight = (int)(sourceHeight * nPercent);
            Bitmap b = new Bitmap(destWidth, destHeight);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage((Image)b);
            g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            // Draw image with new width and height  
            g.DrawImage(_img, 0, 0, destWidth, destHeight);            
                       
            return b;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This class essentially does the same as the C# variant, without using temp files. The main method is only included as a usage example.

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class ImageCapture {

    public static void capture( String fileName, Point firstCoordinate, Point secondCoordinate, int enlargeImageByPercentage) throws AWTException, IOException {
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(firstCoordinate);
        rectangle.add(secondCoordinate);
        BufferedImage image = new Robot().createScreenCapture(rectangle);
        BufferedImage resizedImage = resizeImage(image, enlargeImageByPercentage);
        ImageIO.write(resizedImage, "JPEG", new File(fileName));
    }
    
    public static BufferedImage resizeImage(BufferedImage image, int enlargeImageByPercentage) {
        BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth()*(100+enlargeImageByPercentage)/100, image.getHeight()*(100+enlargeImageByPercentage)/100, image.getType());
        Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D) resizedImage.getGraphics();
        graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
        graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC);
        graphics.drawImage(image, 0, 0, resizedImage.getWidth(), resizedImage.getHeight(), null);
        return resizedImage;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ImageCapture.capture("screenshot.jpg", new Point(100, 100), new Point(200,150), 250);
    }
}
```

Comment: thats so much thats what i am looking for
can you please help me make code for 
resizeImage method
or we are already resizing in the code in below lines

graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
  graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC);
  graphics.drawImage(image, 0, 0, resizedImage.getWidth(), resizedImage.getHeight(), null);

Comment: I extracted the resize-method to match the C# code and to improve readability. But, yes, the original answer did the resize-operation in those lines quoted by you.